# Logging errors from external site

Tags: c#, asp.net, error-handling

There is this web site in .NET 2.0 that is being served on a separate server, I have a sql server where I can add a error logging table. He wants me to help him create something that will log all his the errors generated by his application. I can create the logging table on my end. What would the best scenario for this?. like for instance:

I can create a small website with one page called "logErros.aspx" and add the logging logic in the .cs file, this web site will have its own web.config file. But what would he need to do from his end to point his errors to my site and how can I get a hold of them? in my logErrors.aspx with the exception and everything?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think it is practical create web application to log errors in another web site. But you can log the errors in a database from the site where the exception occurred and then those exception details can be view by other applications.

Tell the person who develop .net 2.0 website to log all the exceptions in your database. Then you can create site to view them.